# API com autenticação JWT

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jwt

Olá, estou construindo uma API a fim de estudos e estou implementando JWT na autenticação da mesma. Todos os conteúdos que encontrei são referentes a Asp.Net Core, como faço para **validar** os tokens no .Net Framework?

Estava acompanhando as aulas com [Macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/18/04/vda230418.htm) porém as aulas são também referentes ao Core.

PS.: A geração do token já está implementada.

Esta é a implementação da action de geração do token.

```
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Usuario usuario)
        {
            Usuario autenticado;

            try
            {
                //REALIZA O LOGIN DO USUÁRIO COM OS DADOS DE LOGIN PASSADOS PELO CORPO DA REQUISIÇÃO
                autenticado = N_Usuario.Logar(usuario.Login, usuario.Senha);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest("LOGIN ERROR " + ex.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                if (autenticado != null)
                {
                    //CRIA AS CLAIMS DO USUÁRIO
                    var Claims = new[]
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, autenticado.Id.ToString())
                    };

                    // GERA A CHAVE DE SEGURANÇA COM BASE NA CHAVE CRIADA 
                    SymmetricSecurityKey SecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key));

                    // DEFINE O ALGORÍTIMO DE CRIPTOGRAFIA E GERA AS CREDENCIAIS PARA A ASSINATURA
                    var Credencials = new SigningCredentials(SecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                    // CRIA O TOKEN DO USUÁRIO
                    var Token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer: "EMPRESTEI", audience: "EMPRESTEI", claims: Claims, expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), signingCredentials: Credencials);

                    //RETORNA O TOKEN CRIADO
                    return Ok(new { Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(Token) });
                }
                else
                    return BadRequest("LOGIN ERROR Incorrect credentials.");    // CASO NÃO SEJA AUTENTICADO O USUÁRIO
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest("GENERATE TOKEN ERROR " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Minha classe Startup também não foi criada.

Comment: poderia me informar qual é a biblioteca do jsonwebtoken e o link da mesma a qual está utilizando? Pois existem diferentes vertentes da mesma.

Comment: using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia.

Você deve primeiramente adicionar 4 referências ao projeto, sendo elas:

1. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin
2. Microsoft.Owin.Host.System.Web
3. Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth
4. Microsoft.Owin.Cors

Feito isso você deve criar um arquivo de inicialização Owin (Startup.cs)

Nele você deve configurar qual a url que ao ser chamada será retornado o token de autenticação.

Após isso deve estar criando um provider que estará sendo responsável por validar a autenticação do usuário, que seria onde você verificaria, por exemplo o usuário e senha, para autenticar o usuário.

Posso um projeto, que uso de introdução para um curso, que possui a conexão com um banco e realização da autenticanção utilizando o Bearer Token.
Nesse projeto utilizo Sql Server + Entity Framework.
https://github.com/felippetadeu/cursoextensao_webapi_netframework_aula1/blob/master/Aula1/DocumentoAula/documento%20aula.txt

Comment: Bom dia, primeiramente obrigado @Felippe. Fiz uma junção de conteúdos e cheguei numa solução não sei se é tão certa quanto a sua, mas implementei de uma maneira pouco diferente. Não utilizei todas as referencias citadas por ti. Criei uma classe interna que herda de DelegatingHandler e implementei a autenticação na mesma, o passo de gerar os tokens gerei normal. Até não me lembro onde achei os conteúdos mas está dando certo aparentemente. Meu projeto encontra-se no GitHub https://github.com/AugustoHTPereira/GiveMe